# Alternative CSS font settings for different browsers?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, font-size

Just curious if there was a way to change font size on a website depending on the browser. I have an @font-face that works in Chrome and Safari, and then my alternative font choice is being used in Internet Explorer and Firefox. My alternative font choice renders larger than my preferred choice. Is there a way to change the font size for only IE and Firefox? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, with conditional stylesheets. Wouldn't you rather get your font-face working all around, though?

Comment: I tried doing a font-face with an .eot so it would work with IE but it didn't.

Comment: Sounds like you are solving the wrong problem. Try presenting the original problem (as a new question), with facts like code used, the origin of the font, and the methods used to generate the different font files.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect the browser using JS and add a class to the HTML tag. You could use the following library for this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

If you add a Class for Firefox and IE, than in CSS you can use

```
.MSIE #mydiv
{
     // Something only for IE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS hacks or conditionals for load css files for a specific browser or css browser selectors...

for css hacks, check out this..https://github.com/ginader/CSS-Hacks
for css browser selectors, http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/