# Change web font-face type depending on browser

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, rule

Is there any simple CSS rule for changing the whole body font-face type by detecting the browser type?

Open-sans doesn't work in IE so I'm searching for a way to change it depending on the browsers.

I tried looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633947/alternative-css-font-settings-for-different-browsers) but still didn't understand how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional comments in HTML, to detect the Internet Explorer lower than IE 11. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_Comments

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[IF IE]><html class="lt-ie11" lang="de"><![endif]-->
<html lang="de">
```

After that, you can define two different CSS rules.

```
body { font-family: Open-Sans; }
html.lt-ie11 body { font-family: sans-serif; }
```

Comment: where to i add the css rules? :) didn't quite understand

Answer (score 0):

Another solution besides adding a conditional comment in your CSS would be to specify a fallback font family in your CSS.

Instead of doing:

```
body {
    font-family: Open-Sans;
}
```

You could do:

```
body {
    font-family: Open-Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

The browser will first try using Open Sans. If it can't find the font, it'll try using Helvetica, then Arial, then finally use the default sans-serif font if all else fails.